# How can i send an array from reactjs to rails?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, rtk-query

i am using rtk query to send update endpoint

```
updateUserRol: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ userId, id, data }) => ({ // data is [1,2,3]
        url: `${url}/${id}/users/${userId}`,
        method: 'PUT',
        data
      }),
    }),
```

but in the backend with rails

```
  def update
      p 777166666, params
  end
```

i am getting in params this:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"_json"=>[1, 2, 3], "controller"=>"api/v1/users", "action"=>"update", "tenant_id"=>"...", "id"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

why i am not able to get roles? instead of _json?

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not a valid option for `fetchBaseQuery`. It has to be `body`.

```js
      query: ({ userId, id, data }) => ({ // data is [1,2,3]
        url: `${url}/${id}/users/${userId}`,
        method: 'PUT',
        body: data
      }),
```

I highly recommend TypeScript for situations like this as that will warn you if you use options that don't exist (and give you autocomplete for those who do).